# Drag and Drop - how to the drop the content into multiple "td"

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, xhtml

I have done drag and drop work using with jquery plug-in, 
Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
    $(".drop1").droppable({
        accept: '.list',
        hoverClass: 'dropareahover',
        drop: function(ev, ui){
         var targetId = $(this).attr("id");
         var allTargets = $("#" + targetId, ".tble");
         $("td#" + targetId).each(function() {

            $(this).append(ui.draggable.text());
            alert(ui.draggable.text())          
            });
        }
 });      
})
```

Html:

```
<div class="draggable">
<ul>
<li class="list" id="1">Teacher1</li>
<li class="list" id="2">Teacher2</li>
<li class="list" id="3">Teacher3</li>
<li class="list" id="4">Teacher4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="drop">
<table class="tble">
<tr>
<td class="drop1 br" id="aa">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="drop1 br" id="ab">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="drop1 br" id="ac">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="drop1 br" id="ad">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="drop1 br" id="aa">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="drop1 br" id="ab">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="drop1 br" id="ac">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="drop1 br" id="ad">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.draggable {
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
.dropareahover {
            background-color:#EFD2A4;
            border-color:#DFA853;
 }
.draggable ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.draggable ul li {
list-style-type:none;
}
.drop {
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
.drop1 {
border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
width:100px;
}
.drop ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.drop ul li {
list-style-type:none;
}
.tble{padding:0px 10px 0px 10px}
```

I want to drop the the teacher1 into multiple td.

Comment: Your code works for me as expected. What do you mean by multiple td?

Comment: Actually, I need the place the draggable text into multiple td. which has the same id.

Comment: Is your table static? In this case you can iterate throught your `td`s using their id `$(".drop"+i)` where `i` is the index of the iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
    $(".drop1").droppable({
        accept: '.list',
        hoverClass: 'dropareahover',
        drop: function(ev, ui){
         var targetId = $(this).attr("id");
         var allTargets = $("#" + targetId, ".tble");
         allTargets.append(ui.draggable.html());
        }
 });      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/tEWQg/

Comment: Link only answer! Please see [FAQ: How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). ... Also, this generates/uses duplicate `id`s.  This is invalid HTML and will cause problems.